# Possible security issue with NIS, or am I just misunderstanding?

Tags: linux, security, unix

I am working in a virtual machine that can communicate with my organization's NIS server. I don't have much experience with it, but I've noticed that I can become another user from my host *without the root password on the NIS server*. In fact, the below prompt doesn't ask me for a password. The behavior is a bit odd, too; perhaps someone can explain why it doesn't work without `sudo` even though I am root.

```
[root@unsecurehost ~]# su - myusername
su: user myusername does not exist

[root@unsecurehost ~]# sudo su - myusername
Last login: Mon Feb 12 19:24:17 UTC 2018 on pts/0
Last failed login: Mon Feb 12 19:28:13 UTC 2018 on pts/0
There were 2 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
su: warning: cannot change directory to /network/path/home/myusername: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ id
uid=012345(myusername) gid=0123(companyname) groups=0123(companyname),9999(othergroupname) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

My `uid`, `gid`, and `groups` are correct.

Ordinarily I'd think of this as a non-issue, but it attempts to access `/network/path/home/myusername`, which is my (networked) home directory. I don't have this storage mounted, but it is possible for me to do so on this host.

I have only configured the `yp.conf` file, which can be read by anyone on our machines, and run `ypbind`.

Would it be possible to exploit this? Some users have sensitive information here, and if I can become another user and access files, this is a security hole. I haven't tried this in a real situation yet because I would like to believe it's not possible (perhaps the networked storage would not allow this, or the "context" field has some importance?). This wouldn't be a very large problem now, but we are working on virtual machines that allow user administrators, which could potentially allow any of our users to become root.

Please let me know what's happening here.

Comment: "but I've noticed that I can become another user from my host without the root password on the NIS server." - There really isn't anything strange about this configuration.  It just means your user, is in the sudo group, and has been given that permission. Which makes sense because you ran the command as root.  As for the fact your not prompted for the password for the user, unless you are connected as the root over an ssh connection, i suspect you did the authentication already for that user when you connected the ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What you demonstrated is not a problem.

You did not obtain any "access tokens" from NIS. The only information you obtained is **the same fields** that exist in `/etc/passwd` – UID, GID, login shell, home directory – and the only thing you did is tell the OS to set your UID to 012345.

You can easily do the same even without NIS, by just creating a local account with the same UID.

However, this does not necessarily grant any access to other machines on the network. Merely knowing your UID isn't enough to authenticate to other systems, and knowing *where* the home directory is doesn't mean you'll be able to access it.

That said, there's one big exception to that: NFS.

#### What you *didn't* demonstrate might be the real problem.

> perhaps the networked storage would not allow this

That's the most important question here – it depends on the protocol used to access your networked storage, and how the storage server is configured.

Most (modern) network protocols always require the client to authenticate. For example, the storage server might require a password, a certificate, or a Kerberos ticket – such information cannot be obtained via NIS.

However, **NFS** in its default configuration (auth=sys) is an exception – it indeed blindly trusts the UID sent by the client. If the client says it's sending a request on behalf of UID 12345, they'll be able to access files owned by UID 12345, no problem.

So take a very careful look at the method you use to mount the networked storage. If it's NFS without any auth= specification, then your file server is wide open – and it's not NIS's fault.

---

Another similar exception is rsh & rcp, which also trusts usernames sent by the client, but *hopefully* nobody uses those protocols anymore. Meanwhile, NFS with auth=sys is still very popular.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I asked the system administrators at my organization and we have several measures in place to mitigate the insecure nature of NFS (IP ranges limited to trusted hosts, Kerberos, and others).

Comment: Kerberos is good.

Answer (score 0):

NIS exists under the premise, that all participating systems are trustworthy - that means, the system administrator, who allowed you to `sudo su` knew what he was doing.

There is no protection (as with any system) against a rogue admin user.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I thought that might be the case, but it seems so silly; the information I used to connect (just the NIS server IP address) is publicly available. This means anyone in our building with a network connection could theoretically become any other user.